# Unity - asset editor downloaded from store isn't showing in Window tab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

Ok, dont know why this would occur as Ive done everything per usual, but I downloaded the uNature asset from asset store and trying to follow their tutorial on how to use it - the video clearly shows that you must pull up the Foliage Manager which appears under the "Window tab"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKByRHAZnzw

Ive tried deleting the asset, reimporting, everything and while the sample scenes run great, I cant make my own because I DO NOT have the uNature option under Window:

[image]

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Did you wait for the scripts to recompile after downloading the asset?

Comment: Ive run the scripts..